# Azure Slot Swap Job Processor failed: Cannot swap slots for site because the worker process in slot aborted the warmup request

Tags: azure

Suddenly started happening consistently across all `Azure App Services` using `Deployment Slots`.

[image]

`Error Message: "Failed swapping site. Error: Cannot swap slots for site because the worker process in slot aborted the warmup request.  This may happen if site has IP Restriction or URL rewrite rules that block HTTP requests."`

Couldn't find any references regarding this issue, not sure if anyone else is experiencing this. Have attempted all suggested solutions in this post https://ruslany.net/2017/11/most-common-deployment-slot-swap-failures-and-how-to-fix-them/ but doesn't resolve my issue.

Nothing was done on Azure Global Configuration scope, and certainly cannot be an issue caused by any single project because this is happening across all projects deployed to `Azure App Service` using `Deployment Slots`.



`Error Resonse:`

```
{
    "caller": "SlotSwapJobProcessor",
    "channels": "Operation",
    "claims": {
        "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/spn": "SlotSwapJobProcessor"
    },
    "correlationId": "xxx",
    "description": "Failed swapping site. Error: Cannot swap slots for site 'xxx' because the worker process in 'staging' slot aborted the warmup request.  This may happen if site has IP Restriction or URL rewrite rules that block HTTP requests.",
    "eventDataId": "xxx",
    "eventName": {
        "value": "SwapWebSiteTrace",
        "localizedValue": "SwapWebSiteTrace"
    },
    "category": {
        "value": "Administrative",
        "localizedValue": "Administrative"
    },
    "eventTimestamp": "2021-04-01T19:44:55.0130397Z",
    "id": "/subscriptions/xxx/resourcegroups/xxx/providers/microsoft.web/sites/xxx/slots/staging/events/xxx/ticks/xxx",
    "level": "Error",
    "operationId": "xxx",
    "operationName": {
        "value": "Microsoft.Web/sites/slots/SlotSwap/action",
        "localizedValue": "Microsoft.Web/sites/slots/SlotSwap/action"
    },
    "resourceGroupName": "defaul",
    "resourceProviderName": {
        "value": "Microsoft.Web",
        "localizedValue": "Azure Web Sites"
    },
    "resourceType": {
        "value": "microsoft.web/sites/slots",
        "localizedValue": "microsoft.web/sites/slots"
    },
    "resourceId": "/subscriptions/xxx/resourcegroups/xxx/providers/microsoft.web/sites/xxx/slots/staging",
    "status": {
        "value": "Failed",
        "localizedValue": "Failed"
    },
    "subStatus": {
        "value": "",
        "localizedValue": ""
    },
    "submissionTimestamp": "2021-04-01T19:45:04.7469589Z",
    "subscriptionId": "xxx",
    "tenantId": "",
    "properties": {
        "Message": "Failed swapping site. Error: Cannot swap slots for site 'xxx' because the worker process in 'staging' slot aborted the warmup request.  This may happen if site has IP Restriction or URL rewrite rules that block HTTP requests."
    },
    "relatedEvents": []
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have an answer (but Stack Overflow won't let me comment :( ), but a corroboration - we've started seeing this recently as well, across multiple app services that have previously auto-swapped very happily.

I've been in contact with Azure Support about this issue, but they have yet to provide a satisfying response.

Comment: Thank for reaching out, this issue has been resolved. Please see my answer below and let me know if the same method works for you too.

Comment: Thanks for the info! Sadly the same fix did not work for us - but Microsoft have since confirmed that there was a platform level bug, and a fix is being rolled out.

Comment: Did your issue ever get fixed yet by Azure yet? The auto swap started failing on us again. Thanks!

Comment: Still no, sadly. We've tried a few app settings regarding changing the warm up ping url, and disabling it altogether - but nothing's worked. We can still consistently reproduce, and consistently succeed at manual slot swaps. Microsoft are still investigating

Answer (score 5):

There could be much simpler solution - staging slot don't have any function deployed, in this case Azure throw the same error message. (Just lost several hours to figure it out, hope it will save somebody else time. :D)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: this answer was sufficient. The error message is not helping at all, so I was looking anywhere else but if the code has actually deployed to staging... Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

This has been fixed. The solution was simply to **turn off the `Auto-Swap` and then turn it back on**.

I turned off `Auto-Swap` because it was failing and causing more inconvenience during the deployment process.

While submitting an issue ticket, `Azure Ticketing System` requires submitting logging data on failed `Auto-Swap` deployment from the impacted `APP Service` in order to analyze this issue.

I turned back on the `Auto-Swap` to make an `Auto-Swap deployment`, `Auto-Swap` worked and it deployed with no issue. I tested multiple times, all succeeded.

No response from `Azure Support Team` on what exactly caused this. But with the upvote of the question, this might not be a stand-alone incident for my subscription alone.

One possible cause our team believe could be `Azure` updated `Auto-Swap`, but the changes failed to reflect on some clients' servers.

Also, to turn on and off `Auto-Swap`, simply go to `App Service` => `Deployment Center` => `Slot` => `Configuration`

[image]

Hope this solves issue for other impacted Subscriptions and App Services as well.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft released a new app setting that you should set on your production slot (or the swap slot if you're swapping between two subslots) called WEBSITE_OVERRIDE_STICKY_DIAGNOSTICS_SETTINGS and set it to 0 (zero). I.e.,

```
WEBSITE_OVERRIDE_STICKY_DIAGNOSTICS_SETTINGS=0
```

The issue is apparently caused when your storage account has network restrictions. Read more [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/8448).